# 100% width, scrollable height background image html and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a background picture to a simple html page. The image should display at 100% width and as it is higher than the screen, a scrollbar should appear to allow the user to scroll to the bottom of the image to the footer.
There is no content overlapping the image as it is a poster for an event containing all the information.
I have tried all "solutions" I could find online, so far none has worked.

So far I have this:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    position: absolute;
    background-image:url('../img/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why not an actual `img` then? `display:block; width:100%; height:auto;`

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: where are your codez

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the missing details

Answer (score 1):

Just use a img like this:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1500" class="myimg" />
```

then css:

```
.myimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

DONE.

```css
.myimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1500" class="myimg" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I am a beginner and sometimes I can  not see the easiest solution. This occupied me for the best part of the day, your reply saved my evening.

Comment: @MaximM no problem, always feel free to ask code related question. If this solved your problem, please accept the answer, thank you!